# Configuration Error : The DNS query name does not exist:_mongodb._tcp.nonr.mongodb.net

Tags: django, mongodb, django-rest-framework, pymongo

```
ConfigurationError at /testapi/
The DNS query name does not exist: _mongodb._tcp.none.mongodb.net.
```

Output with error:

[image: Output with error]

utlis.py
for extracting db list from mongo db
This code works fine when run on a different python file, but I'm getting error when I run with a django project.

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
from pymongo import MongoClient

def auth(username, password, cluster_uri):
username = quote_plus(username)
password = quote_plus(password)
conn_str = "mongodb+srv://{}:{}@{}.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority".format(
username,
password,
cluster_uri
)
return MongoClient(conn_str)

def getDatabaseList(username, password, cluster_address):
client = auth(username, password, cluster_address)
dbs = client.list_database_names()  # returns a list of databases
return dbs
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import permission_classes
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny, IsAuthenticated
from .utils import getDatabaseList

u/permission_classes([AllowAny])
class TestViewSet(APIView):
def post(self, request):
username = request.data.get('username')
password = request.data.get('password')
cluster_address = request.data.get('cluster_address')
dblist = getDatabaseList(username, password, cluster_address)
return Response({'dblist': dblist}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Maybe this link will help you: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/none-of-dns-query-names-exist-mongodb-tcp-mongodb-tcp-local/40913/7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. Instead of using `request.get.data('name')`
using `request.POST['name']` worked flawlessly